# Let $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ with $m^*(A)=0$. Prove $m^*(A \cup B)=m^*(B).$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ with $m^*(A)=0$. Prove $m^*(A \cup B)=m^*(B).$

$m^*(A \cup B)=m^*(A) + m^*(B)$ if A and B are disjoint.

In general, $$m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B)=0+m^*(B)=m^*(B)$$ but $m^*(A \cup B) < m^*(B)$ is impossible so $m^*(A \cup B)=m^*(B).$

Is that valid or am I missing something?

Comment: It's true. Just apply sub-additivity and monotonicity.

Comment: Right. $m*(A\cup B)\leq m*(A)+m*(B)=m*(B)$, but on the other hand $m*(B)\leq m*(A\cup B)$

Answer (score -1):

First, since $m^*(A) =0$. Then, $$m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B) \leq m^*(B).$$
It suffices to show that $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B)$. We need to consider three cases.

---

If $A = \emptyset$, then $A \cup B = B$ and $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(B)$.

---

If $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq B$, then $A \cup B = B$ and $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(B)$.

---

If $\emptyset \neq A \nsubseteq  B$, then $B \subset A \cup B$ and $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B)$.

---

As you can see all the three cases gives $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B)$ as required.

Comment: Why would you do all that case consideration? We have $B\subseteq A\cup B$ anyways.

Comment: Isn't it immediate in any case that  $B \subset A \cup B$, and the inequality follows by monotonicity ?